# Does MyBatis 3 need public setters?

Tags: java, sql, persistence, mybatis

Does MyBatis 3 need public setters (or getters) in the classes it maps SQL to/from ? Is it possible to force it to use reflection?

Answer (score 3):

I tried a while ago and I think it just worked. That was in ibatis though.

What mybatis supports (and it is documented) is constructor injection. By using the constructor tag in the resultMap you can specify arguments. You do need to have a matching constructor which can be annoying, but it allows you to build immutable objects and avoid setters.

http://www.mybatis.org/core/sqlmap-xml.html